# jQuery + PHP Multi-File Drag-Drop Upload Can't Create Thumbnails - WEIRD

Tags: php, jquery, upload, drag-and-drop

Been working on this annoying son of a gun for 3 days. Hoping someone will be able to offer some assistance. Basically I'm using http://tutorialzine.com/2011/09/html5-file-upload-jquery-php/ to allow multiple file uploads along side with a regular file upload input. The first part of this code is the copying of the original image that was uploaded. That works fine for both. The second part is for thumbnails and it won't work when using the drag-drop script, however it works perfectly using the standard upload. I'm assuming my problem isn't with this code, but I'm including it just to show you. I'll also include almost all the other code in case you find it pertinent and helpful in diagnosing.

```
    // copying original image to new location with new name
    $prev = file_get_contents($pic['tmp_name']);
    $new = fopen($file, "w");
    fwrite($new, $prev);
    fclose($new);

    //create image for thumbnail
    switch(strtolower($pic['type']))
    {
        case 'image/jpeg':
            $image = imagecreatefromjpeg($pic['tmp_name']);
            break;
        case 'image/png':
            $image = imagecreatefrompng($pic['tmp_name']);
            imagealphablending($image, true); // setting alpha blending on
            imagesavealpha($image, true);
            break;
        case 'image/gif':
            $image = imagecreatefromgif($pic['tmp_name']);
            break;
        default:
            exit('Unsupported type: '.$pic['type']);
    }

    // Target dimensions
    $max_width = 150;
    $max_height = 150;

    // Get current dimensions
    $old_width  = imagesx($image);
    $old_height = imagesy($image);

    // Calculate the scaling we need to do to fit the image inside our frame
    $scale = min($max_width/$old_width, $max_height/$old_height);

    // Get the new dimensions
    $new_width  = ceil($scale*$old_width);
    $new_height = ceil($scale*$old_height);

    // Create new empty image
    $new = imagecreatetruecolor($new_width, $new_height);

    // Resize old image into new
    imagecopyresampled($new, $image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $new_width, $new_height, $old_width, $old_height);

    // Catch the imagedata
    ob_start();
    //create image for thumbnail
    switch(strtolower($pic['type']))
    {
        case 'image/jpeg':
            imagejpeg($new, $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/".$thumbnail, 90);
            break;
        case 'image/png';
            imagepng($new, $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/".$thumbnail, 9);
            break;
        case 'image/gif':
            imagegif($new, $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/".$thumbnail, 9);
            break;
        default:
            exit('Unsupported type: '.$pic['type']);
    }

    chmod($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/".$thumbnail,0755);

    $data = ob_get_clean();

    // Destroy resources
    imagedestroy($image);
    imagedestroy($new);
```

The HTML

```
<h1>Upload Image(s)</h1>
<form action='ajax/post_file.php' method='post' enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type='file' name='file'><input type='hidden' name='drag_drop' value='yes'><input type='submit' value='go'>
    </form>
        <!-- Our CSS stylesheet file -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="ajax/drag_drop_uploads/css/styles.css" />
        <div id="dropbox" style='height: 400px; overflow: auto;'>
        <span class="message">Drop images here to upload. <br /><i>(they will be automatically uploaded to your account)</i></span>
    </div>
```

The JQuery plugin that handles the drag-drop upload

```
         (function(jQuery){

jQuery.event.props.push("dataTransfer");
var opts = {},
    default_opts = {
        url: '',
        refresh: 1000,
        paramname: 'userfile',
        maxfiles: 25,
        maxfilesize: 5, // MBs
        data: {},
        drop: empty,
        dragEnter: empty,
        dragOver: empty,
        dragLeave: empty,
        docEnter: empty,
        docOver: empty,
        docLeave: empty,
        beforeEach: empty,
        afterAll: empty,
        rename: empty,
        error: function(err, file, i){alert(err);},
        uploadStarted: empty,
        uploadFinished: empty,
        progressUpdated: empty,
        speedUpdated: empty
    },
    errors = ["BrowserNotSupported", "TooManyFiles", "FileTooLarge"],
    doc_leave_timer,
    stop_loop = false,
    files_count = 0,
    files;

jQuery.fn.filedrop = function(options) {
    opts = jQuery.extend( {}, default_opts, options );

    this.bind('drop', drop).bind('dragenter', dragEnter).bind('dragover', dragOver).bind('dragleave', dragLeave);
    jQuery(document).bind('drop', docDrop).bind('dragenter', docEnter).bind('dragover', docOver).bind('dragleave', docLeave);
};

function drop(e) {
    opts.drop(e);
    files = e.dataTransfer.files;
    if (files === null || files === undefined) {
        opts.error(errors[0]);
        return false;
    }

    files_count = files.length;
    upload();
    e.preventDefault();
    return false;
}

function getBuilder(filename, filedata, boundary) {
    var dashdash = '--',
        crlf = '\r\n',
        builder = '';

    jQuery.each(opts.data, function(i, val) {
        if (typeof val === 'function') val = val();
        builder += dashdash;
        builder += boundary;
        builder += crlf;
        builder += 'Content-Disposition: form-data; name="'+i+'"';
        builder += crlf;
        builder += crlf;
        builder += val;
        builder += crlf;
    });

    builder += dashdash;
    builder += boundary;
    builder += crlf;
    builder += 'Content-Disposition: form-data; name="'+opts.paramname+'"';
    builder += '; filename="' + filename + '"';
    builder += crlf;

    builder += 'Content-Type: application/octet-stream';
    builder += crlf;
    builder += crlf; 

    builder += filedata;
    builder += crlf;

    builder += dashdash;
    builder += boundary;
    builder += dashdash;
    builder += crlf;
    return builder;
}

function progress(e) {
    if (e.lengthComputable) {
        var percentage = Math.round((e.loaded * 100) / e.total);
        if (this.currentProgress != percentage) {

            this.currentProgress = percentage;
            opts.progressUpdated(this.index, this.file, this.currentProgress);

            var elapsed = new Date().getTime();
            var diffTime = elapsed - this.currentStart;
            if (diffTime >= opts.refresh) {
                var diffData = e.loaded - this.startData;
                var speed = diffData / diffTime; // KB per second
                opts.speedUpdated(this.index, this.file, speed);
                this.startData = e.loaded;
                this.currentStart = elapsed;
            }
        }
    }
}



function upload() {
    stop_loop = false;
    if (!files) {
        opts.error(errors[0]);
        return false;
    }
    var filesDone = 0,
        filesRejected = 0;

    if (files_count > opts.maxfiles) {
        opts.error(errors[1]);
        return false;
    }

    for (var i=0; i<files_count; i++) {
        if (stop_loop) return false;
        try {
            if (beforeEach(files[i]) != false) {
                if (i === files_count) return;
                var reader = new FileReader(),
                    max_file_size = 1048576 * opts.maxfilesize;

                reader.index = i;
                if (files[i].size > max_file_size) {
                    opts.error(errors[2], files[i], i);
                    filesRejected++;
                    continue;
                }

                reader.onloadend = send;
                reader.readAsBinaryString(files[i]);
            } else {
                filesRejected++;
            }
        } catch(err) {
            opts.error(errors[0]);
            return false;
        }
    }

    function send(e) {
        // Sometimes the index is not attached to the
        // event object. Find it by size. Hack for sure.
        if (e.target.index == undefined) {
            e.target.index = getIndexBySize(e.total);
        }

        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest(),
            upload = xhr.upload,
            file = files[e.target.index],
            index = e.target.index,
            start_time = new Date().getTime(),
            boundary = '------multipartformboundary' + (new Date).getTime(),
            builder;

        newName = rename(file.name);
        if (typeof newName === "string") {
            builder = getBuilder(newName, e.target.result, boundary);
        } else {
            builder = getBuilder(file.name, e.target.result, boundary);
        }

        upload.index = index;
        upload.file = file;
        upload.downloadStartTime = start_time;
        upload.currentStart = start_time;
        upload.currentProgress = 0;
        upload.startData = 0;
        upload.addEventListener("progress", progress, false);

        xhr.open("POST", opts.url, true);
        xhr.setRequestHeader('content-type', 'multipart/form-data; boundary=' 
            + boundary);

        xhr.sendAsBinary(builder);  

        opts.uploadStarted(index, file, files_count);  

        xhr.onload = function() { 
            if (xhr.responseText) {
            var now = new Date().getTime(),
                timeDiff = now - start_time,
                result = opts.uploadFinished(index, file, jQuery.parseJSON(xhr.responseText), timeDiff);
                filesDone++;
                if (filesDone == files_count - filesRejected) {
                    afterAll();
                }
            if (result === false) stop_loop = true;
            }
        };
    }
}

function getIndexBySize(size) {
    for (var i=0; i < files_count; i++) {
        if (files[i].size == size) {
            return i;
        }
    }

    return undefined;
}

function rename(name) {
    return opts.rename(name);
}

function beforeEach(file) {
    return opts.beforeEach(file);
}

function afterAll() {
    return opts.afterAll();
}

function dragEnter(e) {
    clearTimeout(doc_leave_timer);
    e.preventDefault();
    opts.dragEnter(e);
}

function dragOver(e) {
    clearTimeout(doc_leave_timer);
    e.preventDefault();
    opts.docOver(e);
    opts.dragOver(e);
}

function dragLeave(e) {
    clearTimeout(doc_leave_timer);
    opts.dragLeave(e);
    e.stopPropagation();
}

function docDrop(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    opts.docLeave(e);
    return false;
}

function docEnter(e) {
    clearTimeout(doc_leave_timer);
    e.preventDefault();
    opts.docEnter(e);
    return false;
}

function docOver(e) {
    clearTimeout(doc_leave_timer);
    e.preventDefault();
    opts.docOver(e);
    return false;
}

function docLeave(e) {
    doc_leave_timer = setTimeout(function(){
        opts.docLeave(e);
    }, 200);
}

function empty(){}

try {
    if (XMLHttpRequest.prototype.sendAsBinary) return;
    XMLHttpRequest.prototype.sendAsBinary = function(datastr) {
        function byteValue(x) {
            return x.charCodeAt(0) & 0xff;
        }
        var ords = Array.prototype.map.call(datastr, byteValue);
        var ui8a = new Uint8Array(ords);
        this.send(ui8a.buffer);
    }
} catch(e) {}

    })(jQuery);
```

The JQuery that is called to and from the plugin

```
     jQuery(function(){

var dropbox = jQuery('#dropbox'),
    message = jQuery('.message', dropbox);

dropbox.filedrop({
    // The name of the jQuery_FILES entry:
    paramname:'file',

    maxfiles: 25,
    maxfilesize: 5,
    url: 'ajax/post_file.php',

    uploadFinished:function(i,file,response){
        jQuery.data(file).addClass('done');
        // response is the JSON object that post_file.php returns
    },

    error: function(err, file) {
        switch(err) {
            case 'BrowserNotSupported':
                showMessage('Your browser does not support HTML5 file uploads!');
                break;
            case 'TooManyFiles':
                alert('Too many files! Please select 5 at most! (configurable)');
                break;
            case 'FileTooLarge':
                alert(file.name+' is too large! Please upload files up to 2mb (configurable).');
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    },

    // Called before each upload is started
    beforeEach: function(file){
        if(!file.type.match(/^image\//)){
            alert('Only images are allowed!');

            // Returning false will cause the
            // file to be rejected
            return false;
        }
    },

    uploadStarted:function(i, file, len){
        createImage(file);
    },

    progressUpdated: function(i, file, progress) {
        jQuery.data(file).find('.progress').width(progress);
    }

});

var template = '<div class="preview">'+
                    '<span class="imageHolder">'+
                        '<img />'+
                        '<span class="uploaded"></span>'+
                    '</span>'+
                    '<div class="progressHolder">'+
                        '<div class="progress"></div>'+
                    '</div>'+
                '</div>'; 


function createImage(file){

    var preview = jQuery(template), 
        image = jQuery('img', preview);

    var reader = new FileReader();

    image.width = 100;
    image.height = 100;

    reader.onload = function(e){

        // e.target.result holds the DataURL which
        // can be used as a source of the image:

        image.attr('src',e.target.result);
    };

    // Reading the file as a DataURL. When finished,
    // this will trigger the onload function above:
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);

    message.hide();
    preview.appendTo(dropbox);

    // Associating a preview container
    // with the file, using jQuery's jQuery.data():

    jQuery.data(file,preview);
}

function showMessage(msg){
    message.html(msg);
}

    });
```

The sample PHP they gave me

```
       $demo_mode = false;
       $upload_dir = 'ajax/uploads/';
       $allowed_ext = array('jpg','jpeg','png','gif');


      if(strtolower($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']) != 'post'){
  exit_status('Error! Wrong HTTP method!');
      }


    if(array_key_exists('pic',$_FILES) && $_FILES['pic']['error'] == 0 ){

$pic = $_FILES['pic'];

if(!in_array(get_extension($pic['name']),$allowed_ext)){
    exit_status('Only '.implode(',',$allowed_ext).' files are allowed!');
}   

if($demo_mode){

    // File uploads are ignored. We only log them.

    $line = implode('       ', array( date('r'), $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'],          
            $pic['size'], $pic['name']));
    file_put_contents('log.txt', $line.PHP_EOL, FILE_APPEND);

    exit_status('Uploads are ignored in demo mode.');
        }


// Move the uploaded file from the temporary 
// directory to the uploads folder:

if(move_uploaded_file($pic['tmp_name'], $upload_dir.$pic['name'])){
    exit_status('File was uploaded successfuly!');
}

    }

    exit_status('Something went wrong with your upload!');


     // Helper functions

     function exit_status($str){
 echo json_encode(array('status'=>$str));
 exit;
     }

    function get_extension($file_name){
$ext = explode('.', $file_name);
$ext = array_pop($ext);
return strtolower($ext);
     }
```

Comment: What error message(s) are you getting? Is it possible the multi-upload isn't populating filetype or similar? Are the permissions on the file the same for both upload mechanisms

Comment: Would the memory limit be an issue if I'm uploading the same image in both forms and getting different results?

Comment: I guess I could change default to create a jpeg from the tmp file, then upload the file and see if it works, then I know it's a file-type issue.

Comment: You know what, now that I think about it and look at the sample code, I really wonder if it's not passing type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As discussed in the OPs comments;

It seems the file upload example isn't correctly populating the filetype resulting in hitting the switch's `default` block (an `exit`)

Incidentally, you may want to swap this to throwing an exception so you'll see something useful in the logs in future